# How can a descriptor be without __get__ and __set__?

Tags: python, descriptor

```
class typed_property:
    def __init__(self,name, expected_type):
        self.storage_name = '_' + name
        self.expected_type = expected_type

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return getattr(self, self.storage_name)

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.expected_type):
            raise TypeError('{} must be a {}'.format(self.storage_name, self.expected_type))
        setattr(self, self.storage_name, value)

# Example use
class Person:
    name = typed_property('name', str)
    age = typed_property('age', int)
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

Is class typed_property used as a descriptor? but I do not see __ get __ and __ set __ defined, isn't a descriptor defined with __ get __ and __ set __ functions?

Comment: No, `typed_property` is not acting as a descriptor. Why do you think it is?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , This line of codes (“name = typed_property('name', str)”)  make me think of descriptor... why prop() function is called when executing code line (“name = typed_property('name', str)”)?

Comment: the `prop` function **is never called**, not in the code you posted, nor if you instantiate a `Person` object. Again, this is not acting as a descriptor. It looks like someone's mistaken attempt at creating one, sure, but it's not acting as one at all

Comment: Yes, you are right! Someone makes it look like a descriptor, but it does not act like that! Thank you, appreciated!